# Flutter Build stuck on Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play

To reproduce the error, the project is a public project I am working on independently that can be viewed [here](https://github.com/aabid-ism/pangolin).

Whenever I run "flutter build appbundle" OR "flutter build appbundle --no-tree-shake-icons" the terminal gets stuck at the first step which is at:
"Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'..."

Any thoughts as to why this is happening is much appreciated.

I tried using --no-tree-shake-icons as a flag to the build command, but it did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aabid Ismail

**I have solved those issues in this way:**

1. Open your app level build.gradle file then
   add some dependencies:

Please change defaultConfig in two lines:-

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19 //add 19 minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true //add this line 
}
```

Please add dependencies in below lines:-

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.3')
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
   jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx' 
}
```

*When you have done the above changes, go to the terminal, type the following command, and wait for a while.*

**flutter build appbundle --no-tree-shake-icons**

**Here You Can Download Your appbundle:**
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XylNIq3nOEgktF8CBNiTHPD533qOc1D0/view?usp=sharing[1]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XylNIq3nOEgktF8CBNiTHPD533qOc1D0/view?usp=sharing%5B1%5D)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. I am still stuck on "Running gradle task 'bundlerelease'

Comment: @AabidIsmail It will take some time then the build will be done and if the build is not done then an error will appear and send me a picture of that error and You can see in my drive that I have created an AppBundle and sent it

Comment: Thank you. You are right, it took around 15 minutes.

Comment: yeah, welcome man.